# Powershell script to clean up folders

Tags: script, powershell

There's a need to do a weekly cleanup of FTP user account mailboxes on our server and it has about 50 user accounts defined. Below is an example of the FTP user mailbox folder structure which each include 5 subfolders or so with one in ALL being named of them being named **"archive"**.

I'm trying to figure out a way to delete the contents of the subfolders *on a weekly basis*; however, I would like to **exclude** deleting anything from ANY of the **"archive"** named subfolders (keeping their contents in place) in any of the user account FTP mailboxes.

### FTP MAILBOX FOLDER STRUCTURE EXAMPLE

```
C:\ftp\ftp-users  --> Root Level
         \jmartin --> Mailbox User Account Root Level
            \jmartin-a1 --> Mailbox subfolder
            \jmartin-a2 --> Mailbox subfolder
            \jmartin-a3 --> Mailbox subfolder
            \jmartin-a4 --> Mailbox subfolder
            \jmartin-a5 --> Mailbox subfolder
            \archive    --> DO NOT TOUCH --> Mailbox subfolder
```

Answer (score 3):

> **Powershell script to clean up folders**
>
> I'm trying to figure out a way to delete the contents of the
>   subfolders on a weekly basis; however, I would like to exclude
>   deleting anything from ANY of the "archive" named subfolders (keeping
>   their contents in place) in any of the user account FTP mailboxes.

You can complete this with simple PowerShell script logic with one of the four I provided you below that use asterisk characters for wildcards of files and/or folders.

The example logic below uses [**Remove-Item**](http://ss64.com/ps/remove-item.html) including the `-Recurse` and `-Exclude` parameters.

I think ***the topmost example (or the one just beneath it) is the one you need based on your description***, but test with all if needed to confirm. I tested and confirmed that these work just fine, and as expected from a test folder in my environment.

I would suggest that you test these in your environment just to confirm you get it to work just as expected for your needs before you run any against production folders just in case.

---

### PowerShell Command Examples

*(Use the below to delete all **files with a file extension** beneath `C:\ftp\ftp-users\*\*\~` excluding ANY subfolders named "Archive" and its contents of the FTP mailboxes at this level)*

```
Remove-Item "C:\ftp\ftp-users\*\*\*.*" -Recurse -Exclude "Archive" -Force
```

*(Use the below to delete all **files** and all **subfolders** beneath `C:\ftp\ftp-users\*\*\~` excluding ANY 
subfolder named "Archive" and it's contents of the FTP mailboxes at this level)*

```
Remove-Item "C:\ftp\ftp-users\*\*\*" -Recurse -Exclude "Archive" -Force
```

*(Use the below to delete all **files** and all **subfolders** beneath `C:\ftp\ftp-users\*\~` excluding the subfolder named "Archive" and it's contents of the FTP mailboxes at this level)*

```
Remove-Item "C:\ftp\ftp-users\*\*" -Recurse -Exclude "Archive" -Force
```

*(Use the below to delete all **files with a file extension** beneath`C:\ftp\ftp-users\*\~` and nothing more so it'll not touch ANY subfolders of the FTP mailboxes at this level so no `-Exclude` parameter)*

```
Remove-Item "C:\ftp\ftp-users\*\*.*" -Recurse -Force
```